# How to avoid Graphene sorting an OrderedDict on query response? (Python, Django)

Tags: python-3.x, django, graphql, graphene-python

I am trying to return a dict of OrderedDicts from a Graphene endpoint in a Django application, by using the GenericScalar type field.
The OrderedDicts are sorted based on value, but the API seems to re-sort the dicts by key.

The OrderedDicts items format is: `{ id : [name, amount] }`

Example of one of the OrderedDicts that I send:

```py
{ 'foods': {
    3: ['apple', 5],
    1: ['banana', 7],
    2: ['carrot', 3]
  }, 
  'animals': {
    5: ['cat', 3],
    3: ['dog', 10],
    1: ['pig', 5],
  }
}
```

What is received in the endpoint response:

```py
{ 'foods': {
    1: ['banana', 7],
    2: ['carrot', 3],
    3: ['apple', 5],
  }, 
  'animals': {
    1: ['pig', 5],
    3: ['dog', 10],
    5: ['cat', 3],
  }
}
```

I am specifically using OrderedDicts because the order is important, but I have not found a way of avoiding Graphene to re-sort the OrderedDicts by key.

This is the how the ObjectType and Query are declared, althought is is nothing out of the ordinary.

```py
class DashboardType(g.ObjectType):
    data = GenericScalar()

class Query(object):
    dashboard = Field(DashboardDataType, id=ID(), date=Date())
   
    def resolve_dashboard(self, info, **kwargs):
        data = function_to_get_the_data(kwargs)
        # up until this point the data is still sorted correctly
        return data
```

The data is sorted as expected up until the response is sent by the Graphene API. I would expect the order to be mantained, but it is not.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
I didn't think it would be so difficult, but I am out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe redefine your graphql model a bit? It seems designed to match the back end storage of the data rather than what the front-end is looking for.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I thought about using the format `{ name : [id, amount] }` to solve the issue, but that would be only temporary since the frontend will have to offer the option of sorting by name OR by amount sooner or later. 
Any suggestions on how to improve the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest as a model:

```
type Thing {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  subthings: [Subthing]
}

type Subthing {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  amount: Int
}
```

Then you could have a guery:

```
query getThings(orderBy: String, direction: String): [Thing]
```

And against that you could execute:

```
query getThingsOrderByName($orderBy: 'name', $direction: 'asc') {
  query getThings(orderBy: $orderBy, direction: $direction) {
    id
    name
    subthings {
      id
      name
      amount
    }
  }
}
```

Your `subThings` resolver could then sort the `subThings` based on the `orderBy` and 'direction' query parameters.

Your return object would then look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": `
    "name": "foods"
    "subthings": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "apple",
        "amount": 5,
      },
      etc…
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This is obviously a better practice to return the data and it is what I have applied. Althought it is does not answer the question of why Graphene is reordering the OrderedDicts, I will be marking it as the accepted answer since it solves my issue by making the structure less lazy and more flexible!

Comment: GraphQL servers tend to return keys in sorted order - I'm not sure if this is part of the GraphQL spec or not but it's quite common.